# iPhoto vs Photo stream vs Image capture

Tags: iphone, photos.app, photo-stream, image-capture

What is the difference between iPhoto/Photo Stream/ Image Capture?

I hope, all the three is using photos. But WHAT is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[iPhoto](http://www.apple.com/ilife/iphoto/what-is.html)** is a digital photograph manipulation software, part of the iLife suite.

[**Photo Stream**](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/photo-stream.html) is functionality by which when you take a photo on one device, it will automatically appear on all your other devices, without syncing nor sending.

**Image Capture** is the Application developed by Apple which enables users to upload pictures from digital cameras, scanners, or iDevices.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I simply want to do the following things. 1. Just want to copy photos from iPhone 2. Just want to copy photos to iPhone 3. Delete the photos when I want. 

So, which one (iPhoto or Image capture) should I use to achieve my requirement?

Comment: I'd use iPhoto with Photo Stream. You'll require a Wifi connection, though. You should take a look at Dropbox, or any other cloud storage, too.